# Errors: unchecked call to JComboBox(E[]) and Run out of Memory

Tags: java

Hello,

Probably my question is very simple but it is my first java program ever and I don't know what to do.

I want to create a combobox that open images. Just that!

But I get 2 errors, 
1. Run out of memory
2. unchecked call to JComboBox(E[]) in line ''images = new JComboBox( names );''

The first error I tried to fix it in eclipse with -Xmx1024m command and now the program runs through eclipse platform but when I try to compile with javac command I get the error 2. Finally when I create a .jar file from eclipse and I run, it doesn't load all images just the first 80 of 310.

Is there another way to write my code in order to load all images and don't have to use so much memory?

I would appreciate if someone of you could just correct my code...

Thank you very much,
Wishmaster

My code is this:

```
package test;  

import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.awt.FlowLayout;  
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;  
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
import javax.swing.JComboBox;  
import javax.swing.Icon;  
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;  

public class ComboBoxTest extends JFrame {  
private JComboBox images;  
private JLabel label;  
private String names[] =  
{  "1.P 1.png",  
   "2.P -1.png",   ....so on to 300 images };  

private Icon icons[] =  
new Icon[] {    new ImageIcon( names[ 0] ),  
        new ImageIcon( names[ 1 ] ), ....so on  };  
 };  

public ComboBoxTest() {  
super( "Testing JComboBox" );  

Container c = getContentPane();  
c.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );  

images = new JComboBox( names );  
images.setMaximumRowCount( 10 );  

images.addItemListener(  
new ItemListener() {  
public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e ) {  
label.setIcon(  
icons[ images.getSelectedIndex() ] );  
}  
}  
);  

c.add( images );  

label = new JLabel( icons[ 0 ] );  
c.add( label);  
setVisible(true);  
setSize( 500, 500 );  
}  


public static void main( String args[] )  
{  
ComboBoxTest app = new ComboBoxTest();  

app.addWindowListener(  
new WindowAdapter() {  
public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )  
{  
System.exit( 0 );  
}  
}  
);  
}  
}
```

Comment: you want to show images only on selection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm correctly understood.

1. Don't create imageicon in beginning . create the only specific image in the item listener.

   ```
   images.addItemListener(  
   new ItemListener() {  
   public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e ) {  
   Icon ico=new ImageIcon(toString(images.getSelectedItem()));
   label.setIcon(ico);  
   }  
   }  
   );
   ```

No need of this :

```
private Icon icons[] =  
new Icon[] {    new ImageIcon( names[ 0] ),  
        new ImageIcon( names[ 1 ] ), ....so on  };  
 };
```

Comment: in line:     
Icon ico = new ImageIcon(images.getSelectedItem()); 
I get this error
'The constructor ImageIcon(Object) is undefined'
and in the line:
"label = new JLabel( icons[ 0 ] );"
I get 'The field Window.icons is not visible'

Thank you Arpit for your quick response

Comment: can you cast it to string using toString()

Comment: Thank You man it is working fine now...
Is there a way to get rid of unchecked errors?
And I also want, if it is possible not to show the .png extension in the Combobox?

Comment: dont add the .png in files of your combo box.

Comment: it doesn't open the image if I erase the .png extension.

Comment: add the .png separately where you are opening the file in your code.

Comment: Arpit Thank you very much... Sorry for not understanding the basics..!

Is there a way to get rid of unchecked errors? Anyone else?

Comment: i think you need to add string : `JComboBox<string> images=new Jcombobox<>(files)`

Comment: I don't know were to add it, I am trying to add it but I get errors. And I was afraid to ask you...:(

Comment: I get these errors:  
  - The type JComboBox is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <string>
  - string cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: The type JComboBox is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: I think that I don't really care about second error since I can create a .jar file that runs perfectly!!! Thank you very much...